# Presta Shop checkout doesn't work goes to main page

Tags: prestashop-1.6

I'm running Presta Shop 1.6.0.14. This problem appeared suddenly yesterday and I am at a loss. My checkout buttons only redirect to the main page, and when I go into the back end my modules tab just takes me to the main page. I also intermittently get the too many redirects error.

Answer (score 0):

We finally found the answer. We had to remove the modules/powatag directory and its files.